# My iOS app does not appear on Firebase dashboard

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-console

My app is live on the App Store and there are no crashes on the front end however when I log in to Firebase I cannot find it on the dashboard. I tried copy & pasting the database URL but I got the message saying that there was an error making the request and that I should try again later. Has anyone else encountered this issue and could advise me on who to contact to resolve it?

Comment: For help with troubleshooting this, reach out to Firebase support on https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: Same issue here,  I recently created a project and added database on the project, I can only access the database from direct URL of the database, but cannot access from my dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Firebase Status Dashboard](https://status.firebase.google.com), there should be no issues with the Realtime Database at the moment.

Assuming that your app was associated with your Firebase account previously and just suddenly disappeared, I have not heard of/ encountered anything similar in the past.

One thing to try is to make sure you are logged into the correct account and have selected the correct project.

Since accessing the database directly through its URL says to try again later, this might be a temporary problem that is resolved shortly.

However to make sure, your best option at this point is probably to reach out to Firebase support directly using [this form](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) (requires sign-in).